# Are there any APIs for RingCentral Meetings to get cloud recordings?

Tags: video-recording, ringcentral

How to get RingCentral Meetings Cloud Recording by using API?

I record a meeting with cloud recording.

I want to use API to get recordings.

Answer (score 1):

APIs to retrieve Cloud Recordings are available at the Account and User levels.

#### Account Level

`GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/meeting-recordings`

API Reference: [Get Account Meeting Recordings List](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Meeting-Recordings/listAccountMeetingRecordings)

#### User Level

`GET /restapi/v1.0/account/{accountId}/extension/{extensionId}/meeting-recordings`

API Reference: [Get User Meeting Recordings List](https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-reference/Meeting-Recordings/listUserMeetingRecordings)